# Stop broadcast receiver from a button in acivity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to stop and start a broadcast receiver through a button click. two services associated with the broadcast receiver should also stop and start with button click how can i do it..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this is the code............

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        PackageManager pm  = Re_editActivity.this.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(currentActivity.this, name_of_your_receiver.class);
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

  b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PackageManager pm  = Re_editActivity.this.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(currentActivity.this, name_of_your_receiver.class);
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to *"stop"* a BroadcastReceiver either on, say a *Button* click, or perhaps in the *onPause()*.

For example:

```
// DECLARED GLOBALLY
BroadcastReceiver receiver;
Intent intentMyService;
ComponentName service;
```

And in the `onCreate()`:

```
// FOR THE SERVICE:
intentMyService = new Intent(this, MyGpsService.class);
service = startService(intentMyService);

// FOR THE BROADCASTRECEIVER:
IntentFilter mainFilter = new IntentFilter();
receiver = new MyMainLocalReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiver, mainFilter);
```

Then to *"stop"* it, all you have to do, is make a call to this method in either the `onPause()` or on the click of a `Button`:

```
// "STOP" THE BROADCASTRECEIVER
unregisterReceiver(receiver);

// STOP THE SERVICE
stopService(intentMyService);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
  private final BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new SmsBR();

  public void onResume()
  {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter);  

  }

  public void onPause()
  {
```

// add the below line in your button click event

```
    unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this code on button click ,it will start an activity through broadcastreceiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast.makeText(context, "MyReceiver Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent myIntent=new Intent(context,MyService.class);        
context.startService(myIntent);
}

}
```

and then create service to be start .........as:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {      
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

```
private void startBroadCastReceiver() {
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, ConnectionReceiver.class);
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BroadCast Receiver Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void killBroadCastReceiver() {
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, ConnectionReceiver.class);
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BroadCast Receiver Killed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

You can call startBroadCastReceiver() in onStart() method and killBroadCastReceiver() Acc to your Requirement