# How to close an android app with a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

I have an app with a `BroadcastReceiver`, app has quit button with calls to finish method and `System.exit(0)` call. Before `BroadcastReceiver` it worked perfectly (terminated the application) but after I added `BroadcastReceiver` it just sends user to home screen. I have `unregisterReceiver()` in `onPause()` and `onResume()` and in quit method. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392281/stop-broadcast-receiver-from-a-button-in-acivity) , no luck. Can you tell me how to terminate my application?

Comment: I assume the quit method you are referring to is the onStop()? Because typically the unregister BroadcastReceiver should be in the onStop() method.

Comment: No, quit is a button.

Comment: Then try putting the receiver unregisterReceiver() in the onStop() method of the activity. And see what happens.